# How to fetch Spark Streaming job statistics using REST calls when running in yarn-cluster mode

Tags: hadoop-yarn, spark-streaming

I have a spark *streaming* program running on Yarn Cluster in "**yarn-cluster**" mode. (**-master yarn-cluster**).
I want to fetch spark job statistics using REST APIs in json format.
I am able to fetch basic statistics using REST url call:
http://yarn-cluster:8088/proxy/application_1446697245218_0091/metrics/json. But this is giving very basic statistics.

However I want to fetch per executor or per RDD based statistics.
***How to do that using REST calls and where I can find the exact REST url to get these statistics***. 
Though **$SPARK_HOME/conf/metrics.properties** file sheds some light regarding urls i.e.

```
5. MetricsServlet is added by default as a sink in master, worker and client driver, you can send http request "/metrics/json" to get a snapshot of all the registered metrics in json format. For master, requests "/metrics/master/json" and "/metrics/applications/json" can be sent seperately to get metrics snapshot of instance master and applications. MetricsServlet may not be configured by self.
```

but that is fetching html pages not json. Only "/metrics/json" fetches stats in json format.
On top of that knowing *application_id* pro-grammatically is a challenge in itself when running in yarn-cluster mode.

I checked REST API section of [Spark Monitoring page](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html), but that didn't worked when we run spark job in **yarn-cluster** mode. Any pointers/answers are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to scrape through the HTML page to get the relevant metrics. There isn't a Spark rest endpoint for capturing this info.

Comment: This is the last solution for rescue. By the way, I come to know that UI team is following the same approach (scraping metrics through HTML page).
Thanks for info.

Comment: Actually there is, as documented [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html). Things might get a little complicated in YARN mode with the webapp proxies, but see the answer below (which should be accepted instead IMHO). Thanks,

Comment: That's not right. It is documented here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html where else is YARN UI / History server picking it from? It must be using some sort of REST API

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to access the Spark REST API using:

http://yarn-cluster:8088/proxy/application_1446697245218_0091/api/v1/applications/

From here you can select the app-id from the list and then use the following endpoint to get information about executors, for example:

http://yarn-cluster:8088/proxy/application_1446697245218_0091/api/v1/applications/{app-id}/executors

I verified this with my spark streaming application that is running in yarn cluster mode.

I'll explain how I arrived at the JSON response using a web browser. (This is for a Spark 1.5.2 streaming application in yarn-cluster mode).

First, use the hadoop url to view the RUNNING applications. http://{yarn-cluster}:8088/cluster/apps/RUNNING.

Next, select a running application, say http://{yarn-cluster}:8088/cluster/app/application_1450927949656_0021.

Next, click on the TrackingUrl link.  This uses a proxy and the port is different in my case: http://{yarn-proxy}l:20888/proxy/application_1450927949656_0021/. This shows the spark UI.  Now,  append the api/v1/applications to this URL: http://{yarn-proxy}l:20888/proxy/application_1450927949656_0021/api/v1/applications.

You should see a JSON response with the application name supplied to SparkConf and the start time of the application.

Comment: Hi, 

*http://yarn-cluster:8088/proxy/application_1446697245218_0091/api/v1/applications/*

is giving me a Html page where as I want statistics in Jason format. Since I do not know the application_id beforehand (programmatically), so as of now I am just looking into web UI for the running application's ID to fetch stats in json format. [application_1446697245218_0091 is my application_id].

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting,  I'm seeing JSON, not html.
Note that "application_1446697245218_0091" is the _YARN_ application id but there is also the Spark application id that is set when you configure the appName in the spark configuration; you want to use the Spark application id when use the Spark REST API.

Comment: Example: `curl http://cmc-c1.d0hxdbqvsmtenbkqzylhziqimh.fx.internal.cloudapp.net:8088/proxy/application_1584017759_0018/api/v1/applications/application_1520584017759_0018/executors` - this actually works and brings me a JSON response.

Comment: Hi, is there a way to keep the api endpoint available even after application finished executing ?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to reconstruct the metrics in the columns seen in the Spark Streaming web UI (batch start time, processing delay, scheduling delay) using the `/jobs/` endpoint.

The script I used is available [here](https://gist.github.com/emaadmanzoor/cc12763a4133ca30fad8be065846ecc4). I wrote a short [post](http://www.eyeshalfclosed.com/blog/2016/07/22/spark-streaming-statistics/) describing and tying its functionality back to the Spark codebase. This does not need any web-scraping.

It works for Spark 2.0.0 and YARN 2.7.2, but may work for other version combinations too.

Comment: Is there a way to get the number of records processed per batch as well?

Comment: @Emad how about when running from Azure HDInsight cluster?